# Was a java.time.LocalDate in last week?

Tags: java, date, time, java-time

I have a weekly statistics system, and I want to check if the last time the statistic was updated was last week. If it was, I want to clear it.

At the moment, the date is stored in a [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html):

```
LocalDate lastUpdate;
```

I already have the daily statistic working like this:

```
if(lastUpdate.isBefore(LocalDate.now())
{
    clearDailyStatistics();
}
```

And I'd like to do something like this:

```
if(/* something here? */)
{
    clearWeeklyStatistics();
}
```

So, the question is: *How do I compare the weeks of `LocalDate` objects?* There is no need for different "standards" of how week is formed - Monday through Sunday will be used (as is already used by Java's `DayOfWeek` class).

Please, keep your comments and answers only about Java 8 [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes, no [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or other external libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try comparing the year and the week in the year, using [WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html#WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR):

```
 LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
 if(lastUpdate.get(IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR) != now.get(IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR)
      || lastUpdate.get(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR) != 
                       now.get(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR))
```

Comment: Does this consider the change of year? If the last update happened last year?

Comment: It checks that the weeks are not the same, taking the change of year into account

Comment: I edited my answer to correct a bug: you need to check that the WEEK_BASED_YEAR are not the same, not the year.

Comment: Important to note that this answer only works because the questioner wants to use a Monday to Sunday week, and that is in line with the ISO definition of a week. If you want a Sunday to Saturday week you'll need to write similar code, but using the `WeekFields` class instead of `IsoFields`.

Answer (score 0):

Add 7 days or 1 week to your date and compare with current date

```
if(lastUpdate.plusDays(7).isBefore(LocalDate.now())
{
    clearWeeklyStatistics();
}
```

OR

```
if(lastUpdate.plusWeeks(1).isBefore(LocalDate.now()){

  clearWeeklyStatistics();

  }
```

Edit:- Consider this solution only if you want to compare the crossing of week in terms of 7 days period , See the comments for more details.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't this just look if the last update happened in the last seven days?

Comment: But i think thats what you want right `and I want to ccheck if the last time the statistic was updated was last week. If it was, I want to clear it.`

Comment: Err, last week being the last period of time from Monday to Sunday, not an arbitrary seven-day period. So if it's currently Friday, the last week was still the last Monday-Sunday period. :)

Comment: Ahh, then you can go with Vakh's solution, its perfect solution for what you want.